# Removing MS Word links with regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

I'm parsing MS Word documents and get the text with Apache POI.

For a paragraph looking like this:

> The most popular fruits were apples and bananas (see section ‘[Common fruits](http://SomewhereInDoc#_Common_fruit_types)’ and subsection ‘[Detailed botanic descriptions](http://SomewhereInDoc#_Botanic_description)’ below).

I get a string looking like this:

`The most popular fruits were apples and bananas (see section ‘\u0013 HYPERLINK \\l "_Common_fruit_types\" \u0001\u0014Common fruits\u0015’ and subsection ‘\u0013 HYPERLINK \\l \"_Botanic_description\" \u0001\u0014Detailed botanic descriptions\u0015’ below).`

There are different types of tags or keywords using "PAGEREF" instead of "HYPERLINK", too, but it seems they always follow the pattern `\u0013 TAGWORD {String1} \u0001\u0014{String2}\u0015`

So what I want to do is remove everything but `{String2}`. So far I have done:

1. RegEx pattern `\u0013(.*?)\u0014` - Result: `{String2}\u0015` (got this from a SO page I can't find anymore)
2. RegEx pattern `\\[A-Za-z0-9]+` to remove the final `\u0015` - nothing happened. What I wanted to express was, remove the word (containing of chars and digits) including the backslash it follows. Also tried `\\\\[A-Za-z0-9]+`, same result.
3. RegEx pattern `\u0013(.*?)u0015` removes the whole link structure
4. Since `\u0013(.*?)\u0014(.*?)\u0015` does the same (removes all), I tried `\u0013(.*?)\u0014[^(.*?)]\u0015`, but it does nothing.

**Alternative:** While loop

```
boolean textWasChanged = true;
while (textWasChanged) {
    int idx1 = text.indexOf("\u0013");
    int idx2 = text.indexOf("\u0014", idx1);
    if (idx1 > -1 && idx2 > -1 && text.replace(text.substring(idx1, idx2+1), "").length() < text.length()) {
        textWasChanged = true;
        text = text.replace(text.substring(idx1, idx2+1), "");
    } else {
        textWasChanged = false;
    }

}
text = text.replaceAll("\u0015", "");
```

The manual removal works, but I was wondering if it can be simplified into a one-liner or something.

Or more specific:

1. How do I write a regex pattern that only keeps `{String2}`? From the regex manuals, it looks like it's possible. I just can't wrap my head around it.
2. Where is my mistake in step 2 and/or 4? I just negated the `(.*?)` part, bc that's what I want to keep. But I obviously don't understand regex enoug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following `Pattern` to replace your entities:

```
String raw = "The most popular fruits were apples and bananas "
        + "(see section ‘\\u0013 HYPERLINK \\l \"_Common_fruit_types\\\" "
        + "\\u0001\\u0014Common fruits\\u0015’ and subsection ‘\\u0013 HYPERLINK \\l"
        + "\\\"_Botanic_description\\\" "
        + "\\u0001\\u0014Detailed botanic descriptions\\u0015’ below).";

// test
System.out.printf("Raw string: %s%n%n", raw);
//                           | escaped back slash
//                           | | escaped unicode point
//                           | |      | any 1+ character, reluctant
//                           | |      |  | escaped \ and unicode point
//                           | |      |  |        | group 1: your goal
//                           | |      |  |        |    | escaped final \ + unicode point
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\\\u0013.+?\\\\u0014(.+?)\\\\u0015");
Matcher m = p.matcher(raw);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("Found: %s%n", m.group(1));
}
System.out.println();

// actual replacement
System.out.printf(
    "Replaced: %s%n", 
    raw.replaceAll("\\\\u0013.+?\\\\u0014(.+?)\\\\u0015", "$1")
);
```

**Output** (line feeds added artificially for clarity)

```
Raw string: The most popular fruits were apples and bananas (see section 
‘\u0013 HYPERLINK \l "_Common_fruit_types\" \u0001\u0014Common fruits\u0015’ 
and subsection ‘\u0013 HYPERLINK \l\"_Botanic_description\" 
\u0001\u0014Detailed botanic descriptions\u0015’ below).

Found: Common fruits
Found: Detailed botanic descriptions

Replaced: The most popular fruits were apples and bananas 
(see section ‘Common fruits’ and subsection ‘Detailed botanic descriptions’ below).
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly! Had to reduce the quadruple "\" to double, since it seems the raw string for the weird symbol is really `\u0013`, not `\\u0013` (but it's `\\l`, I will correct this in a sec).
Also thank you very much for the explanation of the used regex pattern! Very helpful :-)